# Is Glove a prediction-based model?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, natural-language

I read "**Improving Distributional Similarity with Lessons Learned from Word Embeddings**" and authors mentioned that *Glove* is a prediction-based model while it is clearly factorizing co-occorrence matrix which brings it close to **SVD** or **LDA**.

Also in *Glove* paper they said:

> Unlike the matrix factorization methods, the shallow window-based
>   methods suffer from the disadvantage that they do not operate directly
>   on the co-occurrence statistics of the corpus. Instead, these models
>   scan context windows across the entire corpus, which fails to take
>   advantage of the vast amount of repetition in the data.

It's not clearly mentioned which category Glove belongs to. Can anybody explain which category *Glove* goes into?

Answer (score 3):

Answer of Omer Levy to my question:

> The distinction between "count" and "predict" models is quite
>   artificial, but at the time (2014), people saw Glove & word2vec as
>   something distinctly different from the more "traditional" approaches
>   (explicit matrices and SVD). One attribute where Glove differs from
>   SVD (and is more similar to SGNS in that sense) is that it uses SGD to
>   optimize a non-convex objective, whereas SVD guarantees an optimal
>   decomposition (according to its objective).

Comment: Quite a [lot](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~ek358/CEWE_Final_lecture.pdf) of [research](http://anthology.aclweb.org/P/P14/P14-1023.pdf) on [NLP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02024.pdf) concludes that the difference between count and predict models is *not* artificial; Maybe its better to label them as [distributional vs. embedding models](http://blog.aylien.com/overview-word-embeddings-history-word2vec-cbow-glove/), though. Plus, there is (Brown) [clustering](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/16.pdf), too. In any case, the distinction probably is anything but artificial.

Comment: As a side note: from [here](www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-1023):  

We owe the first term to Hinrich Schutze (p.c.). Predictive
DSMs are also called neural language models, because
their supervised context prediction training is performed with
neural networks, or, more cryptically, “embeddings”.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of both, but mainly I'd categorize it as prediction based, but using the help of counts. Note that the Glove paper describes a classifier to optimize the cost function in Eqn. (8) as a WLS regression problem. Or, as taken directly from their conclusions:

> We construct a model that utilizes this main benefit of count data while simultaneously capturing the meaningful linear substructures prevalent in recent log-bilinear prediction-based methods like word2vec.